# Add box-shadow to colorbox?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, css

I am using the jQuery plugin Colorbox.  Almost perfect, but I'm trying to add a CSS3 box-shadow to the box, and so far nothing seems to work.

I am using

```
#cboxLoadedContent{
        background:rgba(121,121,121,.8); 
        padding:30px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 2px 2px 8px;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 2px 2px 8px;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 4px 4px 8px;
    }
```

The background color and padding are working fine, but no shadow.Anyone ever get this to wok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

```
#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper
{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}
```

The overflow: hidden crops off the shadow. It was there all along. Doesn't seem to be needed either.

Comment: You rock! I had been searching like crazy for an hour now. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order:

```
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
```

### Explanation

The parameters are as follows:

1. **The horizontal offset** of the shadow, positive means the shadow will be on the right of the box, a negative offset will put the shadow on the left of the box.
2. **The vertical offset** of the shadow, a negative one means the box-shadow will be above the box, a positive one means the shadow will be below the box.
3. **The blur radius** (optional), if set to 0 the shadow will be sharp, the higher the number, the more blurred it will be.
4. **The spread radius** (optional), positive values increase the size of the shadow, negative values decrease the size. Default is 0 (the shadow is same size as blur).
5. **Color**

Comment: Thanks. I copied what Compass compiled out to. I also tried it the way you have above, still no luck though.

Comment: Found it:  `#colorbox, #cboxOverlay, #cboxWrapper{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999; overflow:hidden;}`  The overflow: hidden crops off the shadow.  It was there all along.